# Type mismatch error in for loop condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am getting:

> runtime error 13, Type Mismatch.

```
Dim H As Long
H = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To H
   If ((Cells(i, 5).Value) = "NA" Or (Cells(i, 5).Value = "#NA")) Then
       Cells(i, 5).Value = ""
   End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 4):

Error values aren't text. Comparing them to <s>text</s> anything other than another `Variant/Error` will throw a type-mismatch error.

Use `IsError(Cells(...).Value)` to handle cells with errors. You can also use `WorksheetFunction.IsNA`.

In this current case, you may also be able to use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)` instead of looping.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Columns("H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: Best practice is to specify the workbook and worksheet for any `Range` , `Rows`, or `Columns` calls (among others).

Comment: Nitpick: comparing them to *anything other than another `Variant/Error` value* will throw a type mismatch error ;-)

Comment: But I have copied and pasted them as paste only values, that should have converted them into text or Is it still incorrect?

Comment: They are still errors - you can test this with the `ISERROR` formula.